# I am unable to detect or mount my usb sticks (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: drivers, partitioning, usb, mount, asus

so I'm having a little issue with detecting and mounting my USB flash drives on my laptop, Asus X550ZA. I've searched around a lot and continuously got similar answers everywhere I went, none of the issues were like mine so I decided to ask here.

1. So here is the gist of it, my USB ports work sometimes for my phone and Xbox1 controller when connected to any of the ports, So I assume they do work and its possibly not a physical issue. Whenever I plug in a flash drive nothing happens at all, no lights, no detection by my computer, even lsusb doesn't detect a sdb for it.

> ophelia@Ophelia-X550ZA:~$ sudo lsusb
>   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b48c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
>   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
>   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
>   Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>   Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

I currently have my Sandisk Cruzer Glide plugged in while running lsusb, as you can see the usb device is not detected. The Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd is not related to the USB device.

> ophelia@Ophelia-X550ZA:~$ sudo lsblk
>   NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
>   sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
>   sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
>   ├─sda4   8:4    0 286.6G  0 part
>   ├─sda2   8:2    0   244M  0 part
>   ├─sda9   8:9    0 363.2G  0 part /
>   ├─sda7   8:7    0     3G  0 part [SWAP]
>   ├─sda5   8:5    0     1M  0 part
>   ├─sda3   8:3    0    16M  0 part
>   ├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
>   ├─sda8   8:8    0 277.5G  0 part
>   └─sda6   8:6    0   450M  0 part

I am completely stumped on what to do here so I would greatly appreciate some suggestions on what to do, and what might be wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: 1. Unplug. 2. Run `journalctl --follow` to watch the log entries flow by. 3 Plug.

Comment: Was unable to find a solution using that recommendation @waltinator

Comment: That was never intended as a solution but a diagnostic.

Comment: @MichaelBay sorry I did not realize, here is the output then.